# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to show an image stored in local directory inside XAML design.

I have the path to local image.

**ImagePage.xaml**

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <ListView x:Name="ViewImage" SelectionMode="None" IsActiveView="True">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
             <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                 <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" MaximumRowsOrColumns="1" />
             </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                 <Grid x:Name="imgGrid">
                      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                          <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                          <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                      <StackPanel>
                          <Grid Height="50" Width="50">
                              <Grid Margin="2" Background="red">
                                  <Image Source="{Binding imgArt}" Stretch="UniformToFill"
                                         Height="40" Width="40"/>
                              </Grid>
                          </Grid>
                      </StackPanel>
                 </Grid>
             </DataTemplate>
         </ListView.ItemTemplate>
     </ListView>
</ScrollViewer>
```

**ImagePage.xaml.cs**

```
string strImgPath = "ms-appx:///Images/Music/localImg.png";
public string imgPath
{
     get { return strImgPath; }
}
imageClaz obj = new imageClaz();
obj.imgArt = imgPath;
```

**imageClaz()**

```
public class imageClaz
{
     public string imgArt { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Sorry. It's a typo. Updated. @Grant Winney

Comment: Does it work if you just hard-code the string in the XAML? [This SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25914645/3538012) indicates that in general, binding to a `string` property will still invoke the implicit converter. So the failure suggests to me that the string itself can't be automatically converted. You may have to write a custom converter, or bind to a property that is actually of type `Image`.

Comment: if you strip away the `ms-appx://`, it might work. behind the scene `/Images/Music/localImg.png` is converted to an `ImageSource` automatically. But I have not testd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage if you are targeting WinRT app.

Just change the imgArt froms string to BitmapImage

```
public class imageClaz
{
     public BitmapImage imgArt { get; set; }
}
```

and set the Image like this,

```
    string strImgPath = "ms-appx:///Images/Music/localImg.png";
    imageClaz obj = new imageClaz();
    obj.imgArt = new BitmapImage(new Uri(strImgPath, UriKind.Absolute));
```

Answer (score 4):

Both answers about *BitmapImage* are only partially right. In fact XAML has a build in converter and you can surely pass there a *string* unless you provide a converter. There may be several problems in your code:

- you are not notifying UI about the change of the property - lack of *INotifyPropertyChanged*:

  *Example :*

  ```
  public sealed partial class MainPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
      private void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
      {
          if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
      }
  }

  private string imgArt;

  public string ImgArt
  {
      get { return imgArt; }
      set { imgArt = value; OnPropertyChanged("ImgArt"); }
  }
  ```
- the second thing - I'm not sure if you had set the *DataContext* of image or its parents:

  ```
  public MainPage()
  {
      this.InitializeComponent();
      DataContext = this;
  }
  ```

A sample you can [download from GitHub](https://github.com/Romasz/WP81RunTime-Examples/tree/master/ImageAndStringBinding).

Comment: this also half true, default string binding only work with image assets that on the project, external image wont work.

Comment: @kirie What do you mean by external image? If the string is valid Uri, then it should work. What have you tried?

Comment: You can just try <Image source="C:\1.jpg" /> this wont work in UWP, but this work <Image source="/Assets/1.jpg" />

Comment: @kirie Of course it doesn't work - you don't have access to that file just like that. Please read more about access to data and files in UWP. Those are not standard desktop applications.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that access to data only applicable when on phone, on desktop even FilePicker able to open almost all file/folder on drive.

Comment: Ok you're right, I use FilePicker unconsciously without knowing UWP limitation when it come to opening file -_-.

Comment: @kirie Really? That would be very nice, unfortunately I don't think so it works that way. Have you even tried to get a file by path - for example `StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(@"C:\test.txt");`? Have you succeded? - also please don't forget to add suitable capabilities and file type associations in manifest. On the other hand please take a look at what tags you are now commenting - though for UWP it will be nearly the same.

Answer (score 1):

Source is of type ImageSource, not string. You can set the view model with something like this:

```
public class ImageClaz
{
    public ImageClaz(Uri uri)
    {
        this.ImgArt = new BitmapImage(uri);
    }

    public ImageSource ImgArt { get; set; }
}
```

Where you use the path to create the Uri:

```
var imgeClass = new ImageClaz(new Uri("ms-appx:///Images/Music/localImg.png"));
```